# VSTO XML ribbon: which callback is called first

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

When creating a custom XML ribbon in an VSTO add-in is there an order with which the various get* callback methods are invoked (e.g. getDescription, getEnabled, getVisible, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Surely there's an order.
But that's an internal implementation detail of Office and you absolutely shouldn't rely on that.

The only order you can rely on is the call of `onLoad` which is guaranteed to come first.

The rest of these methods should not rely on each other. They should be implemented as stateless as possible and should only return the requested value. (Hence their names starting with `get...`.)
That is, you get the id of the control in and have to return some value - maybe with some information from the current `Excel.Application`.

One additional information:
If you need a refresh of all these `get...` methods, you can call `IRibbonUI.Invalidate()`.
(You get the instance of `IRibbonUI` as a parameter of the `onLoad` call.)

Comment: I've been using invalidate on one or a bunch of my controls within my custom ribbon and have noticed that the order of calls of the various `get*` methods is always the same, within a single control and among a set of them but to make for example I expected the `getVisible` method to be called first for each control since reasonably if the control is not visible the other methods could very well not be called. But this is not occurring leaving me somewhat confused.

Comment: @noplace It's not surprising that the order of calls you experienced stayed the same. But it could deviate in different versions or editions of Office and it can change at any time without further notice. I'm developing Excel add-ins using COM, custom ribbons and VSTO for many years now and especially for Office 2016 chances are very high that even the regular automatic updates change the internal behavior and the order of calls. Strange `COMExceptions` and `AccessViolations` have been the consequences in my case. May I ask: Why do you even need a special order of calls in the first place?

Comment: In an add-in I developed recently I unfortunately had to keep a state and the `onLoad` method when invalidating single user controls is not called anymore. Is `onLoad` invoked again if invalidating the entire ribbon? @haindl would you suggest me a good book on topic of VSTO (I know that microsoft is pushing web add-ins but they are still somewhat limited)....I know that the one published my apress is the most recent but I'm not sure if it is also valid.

Comment: @noplace No, `onLoad` is only called once. But I still don't understand why you need to refresh some state in the `get*` callbacks. As mentioned in my answer you can use `Excel.Application` anywhere. So you can e.g. subscribe to `WorkbookOpen/De/Activate` in the `onLoad` method and react to changes. You can also query the `Application` in the `get*` methods to get the information you need. If you need some other state then just make it independent of the call order. I know of no new books for VSTO but the technology surely hasn't changed so you can try [this one](https://amzn.com/0321533216/).

Comment: It's not an excel add-in but an outlook add-in and I might be doing something wrong due to my incorrect understanding of how things work. From what I understand there is a single instance of my custom ribbon shared among different outlook explorer/inspector windows. However at a given time the ribbon might have a different state (also at the UI level) on the different windows based user actions and the outlook item being displayed. I'm able to handle everything correctly by using custom properties that I attach to the active item in each window and by appropriately invalidating controls.